# C# логика работы со строками

Tags: c#, строки, консоль

Подскажите логику работы со строками

Есть список one в нем 20 строк и второй список two в нем 100 строк.
Нужно чтобы если я указал использовать строку из списка one, 5 раз например, чтобы он записал в лог 5 строк из списка one, и первую строку из списка two. То есть, логика чтобы использовался список one 5 раз на 1 строку списка two

Comment: А при чем тут строки? Это работа с циклами ведь. Берете цикл `for`, указываете ему нужное кол-во итераций, выводите нужною строку из одного списка, а после, прям внутри цикла, делаете еще цикл `for` с нужным числом и уже внутри проходитесь по второму списку, вот вам и будет 5 раз на 1 строку...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо